# Is it possible to send audio from matlab to unity? I get the error Too many output arguements

Tags: matlab, unity-game-engine, tcp, server

First off, I'm rather new to this and are looking for some suggestions/help so I can learn.
I'm trying to set up a TCP server/client with Unity as the server and Matlab as the client which is working fine but the only data I'm able to receive in Unity from Matlab are strings.

I get the following error from Matlab
"Error using sound
Too many output arguments.

Error in MatLabServer (line 15)
b = sound(y,Fs);"

It works fine with just strings but not with any other data type. I tried with arrays, matrices and sound but with no luck.

Unity Server Code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class client : MonoBehaviour {

    TcpListener listener;
    String msg;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8052);             
        listener.Start();
        print ("is listening");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!listener.Pending ())
        {
        } 
        else 
        {
            print ("socket comes");
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient ();
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream ();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (ns);
            msg = reader.ReadToEnd();
            print (msg);

        }

    }
}
```

Matlab Client Code

```
clc
clear all

tcpipClient = tcpip('127.0.0.1',8052,'NetworkRole','Client');

set(tcpipClient,'Timeout',30);

fopen(tcpipClient);

[y,Fs] = audioread('AcGtr.wav');

a = 'hello this is a test';
fwrite(tcpipClient,a);

b = sound(y,Fs);
fwrite(tcpipClient,b);

fclose(tcpipClient);
```

The expected output is 
1. to get unity to load the audio file from matlab and play it
2. have a light source in unity react to the music's frequencies

Comment: Because your `msg` is a string. Matlab might not care about the type but C# does. You can maybe use `var msg = reader.ReadToEnd();` instead but you still have to handle this issue in Unity side

Comment: Okay now that i look again i realized you are using stream reader. `msg` should be a string. Then you can maybe parse it but it will be messy.

Comment: You error has nothing to do with unity. The `sound` command plays a sound. It has no output arguments. `b = sound(...)` makes no sense, what should `b` be? This is what causes the error. https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sound.html Are you trying to send raw audio samples? Just send `y` then, no need for calling `sound`. That said, I couldn't get from your explanation what you are trying to do.